# Presentation Error:Word Reversal

Tags: c++

I have problem with this question I don't know what is wrong with my code that I get Presentation Error every time I don't know what is the format of output can you help me to solve this question I am sorry that my code is a little confusing

here is the link of question http://sharecode.ir/section/problemset/problem/1208

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string temp=" ";
    bool cheak3=false,cheak4=false;
    int n,num;
    cin>>n;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        if(cheak4 == true)
            cout<<endl;
        cheak4=true;
        cin>>num;
        cheak3=false;
        string cheak1,cheak;
        while(1)
        {
            if(num ==-1)
                break;
            getline(cin,temp);
            for(int i=0 ; i<temp.size() ; i++)
            {
                if(temp[i] != ' ')
                    cheak.push_back(temp[i]);
                else
                {
                    reverse(cheak.begin(),cheak.end());
                    cheak1+=cheak;
                    cheak.clear();
                    if(cheak3 == true)
                        cheak1.push_back(' ');
                }
            }
            reverse(cheak.begin(),cheak.end());
            cheak1+=cheak;
            cheak.clear();
            num--;
            if(cheak3 == true)
            {
                cheak1.push_back(' ');
                cout<<cheak1<<endl;
                cheak1.clear();
            }
            cheak3=true;
            }
        n--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with something smaller: write a function that reverses the letters in one word.

Comment: The problem appears to be in the placement of endl statements (and maybe spaces). For example instead of putting the endl statement in the beginning of the while loop, try putting it at the end.

Comment: &AbhishekBansal I try it but I still get Presentation Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the tricky part is you should print a blank line **between** the output blocks.

Your code has too complicated logic! Here is my solution to this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    
int main() {
    int N, lines;
    string word;
    cin>>N;
    while (N--) {
        cin>>lines;
        while (lines--) {
            char end;
            do {
                cin >> word;
                end = cin.get();
                for (int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) cout<<word[i];
                cout << end;
            } while (end != '\n');
        }
        if (N) cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The line `if (N) cout << endl;` makes sure you print a newline character for every output block except the last one (when N equals to 0).

After reading each word in a line, you can use `cin.get();` in order to determine the next character. If it is a space, then print it and read the next word. Else if it is a `\n` print it and go to next line! :)

Comment: Thanks so much :) your code is amazing.Actually I was waiting for you to answer my problem because the only person that can solve `sharecode` problem is YOU